# Trace a route in a MapView iOS

Tags: ios, android-mapview, kml, routes

I'm trying to draw a route in a mapView from an Array with locacions.

I have been looking for in Google and I found that it could be possible using KML files and KML Parser library of Apple. I have tested and it works but I don't know how can I generare the KML file from my array.

I don't know if it's the best way I should take. Otherwise please could you help me to do what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a discussion that might be interesting here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834523/drawing-a-route-in-mapkit-in-iphone-sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this project on github](https://github.com/gimenete/iOS-boilerplate)

It has a module on showing routes with other stuff