# regex and ios5 stringByMatching ==> NSRegularExpression

Tags: regex, ios5

How do I change this line with the equivalent NSRegularExpression

```
NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];
```

Thank you

Comment: can you implement this one is in your application ? or is it working now ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember that you need iOS 4.0 or greater to use this:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" options:0 error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:apiResponse options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [apiResponse length])];
NSString *encodedPoints = [apiResponse substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hello, i tried your code but didn't get any value in regex,match and endpoints objects. it may be because of changes on google map services. so can you please give me the newly change code related to this google map service.

Comment: while using this got crash Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'
do you have any idea..