# How to plot route on a map?

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to plot route on a mapview? I can do it through opening a webview, but is there a way to plot it inside the application?

Comment: Check out http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Maps_on_the_iPhone_with_MapKit_and_the_MKMapView_Class and http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through below links which includes Github project:

1. https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions
2. https://github.com/route-me/route-me/tree/master/samples

This is just the demo applications you need to edit as per your requirements.

Comment: @Surya: i am wondering why google restrict in its license terms to draw routes on MapKit when we can do it, i mean, if you try to submit your project to the AppStore, will it be validated?

Answer (score 0):

If oyou are thinking of drawing a route between two locations obtained from Google API then unfortunately, Google license won't let you do what:

> 10.9 use the Service or Content with any products, systems, or applications for or in connection with:
>
> (a) real time navigation or route guidance, including but not limited
>   to turn-by-turn route guidance that is synchronized to the position of
>   a user's sensor-enabled device;
>
> (b) any systems or functions for automatic or autonomous control of
>   vehicle behavior; or
>
> (c) dispatch, fleet management, business asset tracking, or similar
>   enterprise applications (the Google Maps API can be used to track
>   assets (such as cars, buses or other vehicles) as long as the tracking
>   application is made available to the public without charge. For
>   example, you may offer a free, public Maps API Implementation that
>   displays real-time public transit or other transportation status
>   information.

Here is a similar question:
[Drawing a route in MapKit in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834523/drawing-a-route-in-mapkit-in-iphone-sdk)