# Implementing get directions in map view

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mkmapview

I am trying to implement a feature to get directions from my custom mapview. The get direction feature is exactly like the one in map app in iphone. I am a bit clueless to start with this feature. Any suggestions will be apppreciated

Comment: I have a mapview class that subclass Mkmapview class. And I am dropping pins which points to addresses that I have in my custom contact listMy application wants the exact features that you find in Iphone maps app. Get direction should accept  source and destination locations and should draw the route exactly like the map app.

Comment: does the link given below helpful to you?

Comment: Could you give me any other links

Comment: You can also google hopefully. I am bit busy today. hope u don't mind.

Comment: @Sarah. Carry on. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many links available stating the same. You should have look at the same. Like the one given below :

[Drawing a route in MapKit in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834523/drawing-a-route-in-mapkit-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

To get the routes you need, use Google Directions API. If you are using Three20, you can use [extThree20Google extension](https://github.com/RIKSOF/three20/tree/development/src/extThree20Google)