# Why This Code Does Not Draw Polyline on MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I have the following code, with which i am trying to draw a polyline between a set of coordinates (which are correct as I also use them to add pins to the map, and those work fine).

I call a drawing method to initiate the drawing like so (the array in the method call contains the necessary coordinates):

```
 [self drawRoute:[[transportData objectForKey:@"19"] objectForKey:@"stops"]];
```

This is the actual method that is supposed to draw the line on the map (selectedRoute is an MKPolyline object):

```
- (void)drawRoute:(NSArray *)routePointsArray {
if (selectedRoute) {
    [mapView removeOverlay:selectedRoute];
    selectedRoute = nil;
}

CLLocationCoordinate2D routeCoordinates[routePointsArray.count];
for (int i = 0; i < routePointsArray.count; i++) {
    float latitude = [[[routePointsArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
    float longitude = [[[routePointsArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lon"] floatValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D routePoint =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    routeCoordinates[i] = routePoint;
}

selectedRoute = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:routeCoordinates count:routePointsArray.count];
[mapView addOverlay:selectedRoute];
[mapView setVisibleMapRect:[selectedRoute boundingMapRect]];
}
```

And this is my delegate:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
MKPolylineRenderer *routeLineView = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:selectedRoute];

if(overlay == selectedRoute)
{
    if(nil == routeLineView)
    {
        routeLineView = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:selectedRoute];
        routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
        routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        routeLineView.lineWidth = 5;

    }

    return routeLineView;
}

return nil;
}
```

I kind of narrowed it down to the routeCoordinates array not getting filled up with coordinates, but I do not understand why.

Also, if you spot any mistakes in the code I would really appreciate if you could point those out to me (possibly with a solution) as I am just learning this part of iOS and can use any help I can get.

Comment: You create an empty `routeLineView` but then compare it to `nil` (which it won't be) before adding the overlay line.

Comment: YEah, I do not quite understand that part. But you are right, if I take out that condition, the line does get drawn.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `rendererForOverlay` method.

The first thing it does is assign an instance of `MKPolylineRenderer` to `routeLineView`, but later you only actually add the overlay if `routeLineView` is `nil`, which it won't be.

Remove the line that assigns the initial value to `routeLineView`.

Comment: If I remove the line, the compiler gives me a "use of undeclared identifier" error.

Comment: You need to keep the declaration, but remove the initialisation.

Comment: Okay, it works this way. However, it brings up the question of why do I even need the nil condition since routeLineView will always be nil. I don't understand the logic behind this condition. If you could please provide me with a properly working rendererForOverlay method that is also in accordance with Apple guidelines, I will accept your answer.

I based my code on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598322/iphone-how-to-draw-line-between-two-points-on-mapkit

Comment: Note that in that answer they are using a property, not a local variable, so they are checking that there isn't already an overlay shown