# Draw a Line between two coordinates in a TMapView (Delphi FMX)

Tags: canvas, line, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a `TMapView` on my Form. The `TMapView` works fine so far but I want to add the possibility to **draw a Line** between two **coordinates** on the `TMapView`. How can I do that?

I tried the following which does not work in any way:

```pascal
var
A,B: TMapCoordinate;
AB: TMapPolylineDescriptor;
begin
A.Latitude:=51.88;
A.Longitude:=10.56;
B.Latitude:=51.9;
B.Longitude:=10.7;
//MapView1.Canvas.DrawLine(A,B,50); //doesnt work
// AB.Points:=[A,B]; //doesnt work too
AB.StrokeWidth:=50;
//MapView1.AddPolyline(AB); //doesnt work too
end;
```

I guess the canvas thing wont work as I want as I think it just connects points on the TMapView as a Bitmap and not on the map itself. Please suggest me how I can draw a Line between two coordinates on the map (if that is possible)

I use Delphi 10.3.3 Community Edition and try to compile it on my android 10 phone.

I found this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598322/iphone-how-to-draw-line-between-two-points-on-mapkit) where the Polyline is used in Objective-C for MapKit on iPhone. I guess I have to do the same thing in delphi, but I have no idea how to do this.. but I saw Polyline draws a maps route between two points. Thats good to know too, but I just want my Line drawn and no maps route suggestion from Google.

if I use this code:

```pascal
  if MapView1.Canvas.BeginScene then
  begin
    Canvas.Fill.Color := $FF111111 + random($FFFFFF);
    Canvas.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
    Canvas.FillRect(RectF(random(300), random(300), random(300), random(300)),
    0,
    0, [], 1);
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
```

it works and draws a colored Rectangle somwhere in some color, but is disappears immediately after showing up.. maybe thats why my Lines arent visible too. Maybe they're painted but overpainted immediately. I Dont know much about canvas of my TMapView or Canvas in general, but after painting the "square" it dissappears and I guess those Lines are just disappearing too. Can I somehow make those selfpainted canvas changes permanent until I overpaint them by myself?

Comment: You probably have to convert from geographic coordinates (latitude, longitude) to canvas (bitmap) coordinates. Try drawing a line from top left corner (0, 0) to bottom line corner (with, height) to see if the line is visible.

Comment: I tried painting canvas but the code I used didn't paint anything:```delphi
var
A,B: TPoint;
begin
A.x:=12;
A.y:=12;
B.x:=strtoint(MapView1.Width.ToString);
B.y:=strtoint(MapView1.Height.ToString);
MapView1.Canvas.DrawLine(A,B,50); //doesnt work
end;
``` So I didn't even manage to draw any line

Comment: ```delphi
with MapView1.Canvas do
begin
    BeginUpdate;
    Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
    Stroke.Thickness := 2.0;
    Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
    DrawLine(PointF(10, 10), PointF(100, 10), 1);
    EndUpdate;
end;
```
this doesnt work too on TMapView

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with [google-maps]

Comment: @geocodezip TMapView uses Google Maps but yes, I see the point. the tag is removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use like that

```
var
A,B: TMapCoordinate;
AB: TMapPolylineDescriptor;
begin
  A := TMapCoordinate.Create(51.88,10.56);
  B := TMapCoordinate.Create(51.9,10.7);

  AB := TMapPolylineDescriptor.Create([A,B]);
  AB.StrokeWidth:=5;
  MapView1.AddPolyline(AB);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was exactly what I was looking for <3