# Turn by turn navigation in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios5, mapkit

I am developing an iPhone application for restaurants. I have used mapkit to show the locations of restaurants. User also have option to see route to a particular location (restaurant) from the current location. I need to add turn by turn navigation in it. I am using google maps and somewhere I read that iPhone does not show turn by turn navigation because that is restricted in Apple-Google contract for maps. Is it really true? If it is, then is there any other way or any 3rd party library, by which I can implement turn by turn navigation?

Thanks in advance

Regards,

PC

Comment: ios6 supports it, when Apple release theirs

Comment: yeah, it has apple maps, but that is full of bugs. Sometimes it shows route that in reality doesn't exists. I can't use that until apple releases updated maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option for navigation is to let the user choose the turn by turn they want:
- Apple Maps using the maps.apple.com
- Google Maps using the maps.google.com 
other apps, such as Navigon, Tom tom.

It is a complicated feature and you're much better off not taking responsibility for any shortcomings of services.

Google Maps licence agreement prevents you from doing turn by turn.

Check [Drawing a route in MapKit in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834523/drawing-a-route-in-mapkit-in-iphone-sdk)