# How to use Google Map API to draw route between 2 locations in iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit, ios6-maps

Previously I used `iOS 5` to draw routes between 2 locations and update the current location continuously while navigating using `Google Maps API`,it was working fine but now after i upgraded to `iOS 6`, nothing is working I am not able to view the map also, Given below is the error i receive when i try to load the map,

```
-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16665e40
2013-05-24 12:07:26.522 DriverApp[988:c07]  WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the     webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -    [__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16665e40
```

Can anyone please help me? I am meeting my deadline and I'm really confused on how to proceed further.

Comment: Can you share some code please!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `LocalizedCurrentLocation` class for ios 5 From this link [localized-current-location-string-for-iphone-apps](http://www.martip.net/blog/localized-current-location-string-for-iphone-apps)

Also See more details from this link answer [how-to-draw-routes-on-maps-in-ios-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246702/how-to-draw-routes-on-maps-in-ios-6)