# draw a color track line from current user location to desire location in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mkmapview

how can we draw a color track line from current user location(starting lat long) to desire location(ending lat long) by using Google Maps API in ios. I have many tutorials but could not find proper guidance.Kindly guide me properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834523/drawing-a-route-in-mapkit-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: I know I've said it before in many other places, but you may have missed it. If you are planning to release this on iOS 6 you'll be breaking the Google Maps API license if you show their data on a non-Google Map.