# Issues in getting directions in mkmapview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, directions

I'm working with getting directions in `mkmapview`, I got code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924208/756941).

In the function

```
- (NSArray*)getRoutePointFrom:(Annotation *)origin to:(Annotation *)destination
{
NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", origin.coordinate.latitude, origin.coordinate.longitude];
NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", destination.coordinate.latitude, destination.coordinate.longitude];

NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];
NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];

NSError *error;
NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];

return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]];
}
```

I got some small issues, searched for solutions, but I can't.

The issues are

**1.Parse Issue**

```
Expected a type
```

in

```
- (NSArray*)getRoutePointFrom:(Annotation *)origin to:(Annotation *)destination
```

**2.Automatic Reference counting issue**

```
 'NSString' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'stringByMatching:capture:'
```

in

```
NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];
```

How to solve these two issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to **Robotic Cat**'s answer, try to do following:

1. Goto: [This code.google Project](http://code.google.com/p/ashiphone/downloads/detail?name=MapWithRoutes.zip&can=2&q=) (As, I got that from there)
2. Open the enclosing folder
3. Find `RegexKitLite` Folder in it.
4. Add it to your project (with `copy file to destination group` AND
   `Add to target` options enabled)
5. Add `#import RegexKitLite.h` to your `.m` file.

Most probably the problem will be solved.

Comment: while doing this error saying "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386" found , how to solve this?

Comment: You have to add architecture `i386` in your project settings. Just google it. You will get that.

Comment: adding the library libicucore.A.dylib and libicucore.dylib solved the issues.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

1. **Delete the file RegexKitLite.h and RegexKitLite.m**

   ```
   -(NSArray*) calculateRoutesFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) f to: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) t {
       NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", f.latitude, f.longitude];
       NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", t.latitude, t.longitude];

       NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];
       NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];
       NSLog(@"api url: %@", apiUrl);
       NSError *error;
       NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
       NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" options:0 error:NULL];
       NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:apiResponse options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [apiResponse length])];
       NSString *encodedPoints = [apiResponse substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
       //NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];

       return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

1: Sounds like an import issue.  Please show us your imports in your header file and implementation files.

2: This is NOT an ARC issue.  You are calling a method that does not exist on `NSString`.  Again, I would suggest that this is an import issue where you have forgotten to import a category that adds methods to `NSString`. Import it into your implementation file. If you don't have this category code then you will need to find it on the web somewhere.