# how to draw a route map source to destination in phone SDK?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, core-location

I am developing iPhone application. I have requirement that is, draw a route map from source to destination in map view location, and the update current movement location.

can anyone give me example source ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried copy-pasting your [Question Title on Google](http://www.google.co.in/#gs_rn=14&gs_ri=psy-ab&pq=how%20to%20draw%20a%20route%20map%20source%20to%20destination%20in%20phone%20sdk?&cp=52&gs_id=8he&xhr=t&q=how%2bto%2bdraw%2ba%2broute%2bmap%2bsource%2bto%2bdestination%2bin%2bios&es_nrs=true&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=how%2bto%2bdraw%2ba%2broute%2bmap%2bsource%2bto%2bdestination%2bin%2bios?&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.bmk&fp=66f7130c38075b35&biw=1366&bih=586) ?

**Answer :** [Drawing a route in mapkit in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834523/drawing-a-route-in-mapkit-in-iphone-sdk?rq=1)

Comment: @iSaravanan : If you find the Answer then mark it as "Accepted".

Comment: give me some source code using Google Map SDK iOS. That is help for me.

Comment: @iSaravanan : try this : https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions

Comment: The above example not working perfectly. can you explain more it will helpful for me.

Comment: This is my requirement i need to draw a path form  current location to one destination location. This are all i want to do using Google Map for iOS  SDK.

Comment: @iSaravanan : You should go with my 1st Opinion. Check that 1st Magic Link. It Answers your Question.