# Free drawing on Maps

Tags: ios, mapkit, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need to create functionality where a user draws (freely) his daily route on a map. Using iOS Maps / Google Maps SDK, how can I achieve it? The MapView will be fixed at a location and a zoom level, so it doesn't move while the user is drawing. The user has to draw a route along the roads shown on the screen. How can I achieve this ?

This is implemented in this [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/map-draw-route-tracking-annotation/id464000751?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)

Answer (score 0):

"There is no way to do that with MapKit: it's easy enough to draw lines when you know the coordinates, but MapKit won't give you access to the roads or other routing information. I'd say you need to call an external API to get your data"

Reference article: [Drawing a route in MapKit in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834523/drawing-a-route-in-mapkit-in-iphone-sdk)